# Linking multiple values in a cell to checkboxes in userform

Tags: excel, vba, find, userform

I have the following search code:

```
Private Sub Search_Click()
Dim Name As String
Dim f As Range
Dim r As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim s As Integer
Dim FirstAddress As String

Name = surname.Value

With ws
 Set f = Range("A:A").Find(what:=Name, LookIn:=xlValues)
  If Not f Is Nothing Then
   With Me
    firstname.Value = f.Offset(0, 1).Value
    tod.Value = f.Offset(0, 2).Value
    program.Value = f.Offset(0, 3).Value
    email.Value = f.Offset(0, 4).Text
    officenumber.Value = f.Offset(0, 6).Text
    cellnumber.Value = f.Offset(0, 7).Text
    if f.offset(0,5).value = "PACT" then PACT.value = True
```

I want to modify the `if f.offset(0,5).value`: If I have one single value in a cell then it's easy to pick that one cell, link it to the checkbox and have the checkbox checkmarked. The problem is I have multiple values in the cell.

The values in the column 6 (f.offset(0,5).values) have the names as the checkboxes eg., checkboxes.name & " " so... PACT OTTAWA VANCOUVER MONTREAL TORONTO

This is done through an add command.

So the column 6 can display PACT OTTAWA VANCOUVER or PACT TORONTO or TORONTO depending on which checkboxes are clicked to add in userform.

If I can read and link to the name of the checkboxes and checkmark the ones that are in column 6 then that would work.

```
if f.offset(0,5).value = "PACT" then PACT.value = True
```

If I do it this way, then I'll have way too many combinations that I have to figure it out using if statements. Is there a way to "read" column 6, match it to the names of checkbox and checkmark the checkboxes in the userform when I click the search button?

***EDIT:***

```
Private Sub Search_Click()
Dim Name As String
Dim f As Range
Dim r As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim s As Integer
Dim FirstAddress As String
Dim str() As String

Name = surname.Value

With ws
 Set f = Range("A:A").Find(what:=Name, LookIn:=xlValues)
  If Not f Is Nothing Then
    With Me
      firstname.Value = f.Offset(0, 1).Value
      tod.Value = f.Offset(0, 2).Value
      program.Value = f.Offset(0, 3).Value
      email.Value = f.Offset(0, 4).Text
      officenumber.Value = f.Offset(0, 6).Text
      cellnumber.Value = f.Offset(0, 7).Text

      str() = Split(inputstr, " ")
      For i = 0 To UBound(str)
       Select Case UCase(Trim(str(i)))
        Case "PACT": PACT.Value = True
        Case "PrinceRupert": PrinceRupert.Value = True
        Case "Montreal": Montreal.Value = True
        Case "TET": TET.Value = True
        Case "WPM": WPM.Value = True
        Case "TC": TC.Value = True
        Case "US": US.Value = True
        Case "Other": Other.Value = True

       End Select

      Next i
```

I've added the following code but nothing happens.

I've searched on msdn but I don't quite understand the str() = split(inputstr, " ") and for I = 0 Ubound (str). I'm assuming the trim function is if after trimming the values of column 6 and case is "PACT" then PACT.value = True?

***EDIT2:***

It seems the code doesn't catch the words other than PACT and I'm assuming it picks up PACT because it's the first one. I've tried manually inputting the column 6 values and see if any names get picked up but it doesn't. Is there a way to fix this?

Perhaps it's because when I trim the data in column 6, it's seen as PACTPrinceRupertTETWPMTCUSOther. Is that why it won't pick it up?

Comment: Read the value from the cell and split it using space as a delimiter. You will get an array. Now simply loop through the array to get the individual names.

Comment: The `inputstr` (that i used) needs to be the `f.offset(0,5).value` (that you used)

Comment: it works but for some reason it only picks up "PACT" and i've double checked the names of the Checkbox and yet it doesn't pick up...?

Answer (score 3):

Just as Siddharth said, Using split() and looping through the resulting array...

```
Dim str() As String
str() = Split(inputstr, " ")

For i = 0 To UBound(str)

Select Case ucase(trim(str(i)))
    Case "PACT": pact.Value = True
    case ....:
End Select

Next i
```

Comment: + 1 Just to be on a safer side, change `Select Case str(i)` to `Select Case Ucase(Trim(str(i)))` and `Case "pact"` to `Case "PACT"`

Comment: Right no Siddharth. Good call!

Comment: @Bigtree so i've done F8 and ran through the code above, but it only picks up PACT and skips the rest of the cases. Is it because the trim makes it PACTPrinceRupertMontrealWPMTETTCUSOther? Perhaps that's why it won't pick up?